# Flask & mod_wsgi app causing ports to stop working

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

My Flask and mod_wsgi app seems to be breaking ports.  Every month or so my page will stop loading and I get a "Google Chrome could not connect to " message, but moving it to a new port fixes it.  I've checked the apache log and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong there.  If I stop apache from listening to the port and run my dev version of the Flask app on one of the ports that the live version has previously used I get the same "Google Chrome could not connect to " message.  While apache is listening Netstat shows that the port is being listened to by apache and lsof -i returns a bunch of apache processes that are using the port. I'm not sure if any of that is normal for mod_wsgi.  If I remove the port from apache both netstat and lsof return nothing but the port still doesn't work for mod_wsgi or flask.

Here is the mod_wsgi part of my config file with the ip, domain, and user/group changed

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8880>
ServerName test.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

WSGIDaemonProcess dash user=user group=group threads=5

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/dash/dashboard.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/html/dash>
    WSGIProcessGroup dash
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# records regular flask errors
ErrorLog /var/www/html/dash/error.log
LogLevel warn
```

Here is my wsgi file

```
import os
import sys

# location of flask app
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flask/dashboard')


from dashboard import app as application

# logs python errors at production.log
if not application.debug:
    import logging
    this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    log_file = os.path.join(this_dir, 'production.log')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    application.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: We are going to need some more information: 1) Are you checking the apache error log as well as the access log? 2) How do you have mod_wsgi set up (i. e. what is the content of your `.conf` file where you set up mod_wsgi)? 3) What does your `.wsgi` file look like? 4) If you restart apache after this happens and *hard reload* the page in Chrome (clear cache and reload) does everything come back up?

Comment: 1) I looked a the access logs but I'm not really sure what to look for.  
2 & 3) I'll add those to the question.  
4) I've restarted apache and used the chrome developer tools to ignore the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the virtual host without an ip address seems to have fixed the issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:8880>
```

Thanks to the mod_wsgi user group who found the answer [[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/modwsgi][1]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/modwsgi%5d%5b1%5d)